# Print image using windows print image dialog passing arguments

Tags: c#, windows, printing

I saw this post [Print image using windows print image dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662130/print-image-using-windows-print-image-dialog), and works fine, but I need to change the number of copies by programming.

What are the arguements I need here?

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = ????;
```

Thanks for advance.

Comment: You can't do that with a command line parameter.

Comment: Really?, yoy know what's the procces of the print image dialog?

Comment: The way you're doing it, it's whatever program registered itself to handle the `Print` verb on whatever image file format you are trying to print. It might be the standard Windows *Print Photos* app, it might be Photoshop, it might be ACDSee, whatever. If you want any control over the dialog, or for it to look the same on everyone's computer, you might have to find an image-printing program that you can distribute with your program and call that explicitly; or implement your own printing.