# opening the Windows Print Pictures dialog using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to call the Windows Print Pictures dialog using VB.net. the one Windows comes up with when you go to print a picture, the one that lets you print full page, 8X10, 4X6, 5X7, contact sheet, etc.

I've tried using printdocument and printdialog but those only give you the standard print dialog window for documents.

I've searched Google and all the results were completely unrelated to the Print Pictures dialog and therefore completely useless.

I've seen the same question for C+ here
[Print image using windows print image dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662130/print-image-using-windows-print-image-dialog)
using CLSID_PrintPhotosDropTarget COM object.
but this doesn't really help me since I'm using VB.net (Visual Studio 2008 to be precise) but I'm including it here as it has a screenshot of the dialog I am trying to call.

Comment: That code that you liked to is C# not C+. C# is another .net language which translates to vb.net.

Comment: if it translates, then that translation is far above the skills of a noob like myself. I tried it and got a list of errors longer then a kids christmas list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just this once, I will translate for you but you need to find an on line converter that you like. Many examples are available in C#.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'The C# code
    'String fileName = @"C:\Development\myImage.tif";//pass in Or whatever you need
    'var p = New Process();
    'p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
    'p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
    'p.Start();
    Dim fileName = "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Graphics\Baby owl.jpg"
    Dim p = New Process
    p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName
    p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print"
    p.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even know there were online conversion utilities. I apologize for my ignorance

Comment: @justanotherdamnnoob Here are a few http://converter.telerik.com/ and
https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/ also
https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/